# GTM and ActiveCampaign Site Tracking - sending email via dataLayer

Tags: google-tag-manager

My goal is to be able to integrate ActiveCampaign Site Tracking with GTM, however, AC Site tracking requires the email address to identify a user.

Is it possible to just add the email via dataLayer for AC? won't that affect the PII rules?